# Distorting images using FabricJS filters and custom controls, by dragging the corner control points image resizes from center

Tags: webgl, fabricjs

I have created a subclass in Fabric.js 4.3.0 extending fabric.Image, this helps me change the render function so that image will always fit in the bounding box.

I have also created a custom filter for Fabric, using which, by giving 4 corner coordinates, I can distort the image, similar to Photoshop's free [transform -> distort tool.](https://youtu.be/Pn-9qFNM6Zg?t=274)

While my code works, the issue is that when I drag the corner controls, the image always resizes from center, moving the other controls points as well.

I am trying to follow [the instructions](http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon) on how to resize objects in fabric using custom control points, the instructions own on polygons, and other shapes, but it does not yield the result required with images.

The result that I want to achieve, is when dragging one of the green control points, the image should distort, but image and the other control points must stay in their own positions without moving, similar to what you see here: https://youtu.be/Pn-9qFNM6Zg?t=274

Here is a JSFIDDLE for the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/human_a/p6d71skm/

```js
fabric.textureSize = 4096;
// Set default filter backend
fabric.filterBackend = new fabric.WebglFilterBackend();
fabric.isWebglSupported(fabric.textureSize);

fabric.Image.filters.Perspective = class extends fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param {Object} [options] Options object
     */
    constructor(options) {
        super();

        if (options) this.setOptions(options);

        this.applyPixelRatio();
    }

    type = 'Perspective';
    pixelRatio = fabric.devicePixelRatio;
    bounds = {width: 0, height: 0, minX: 0, maxX: 0, minY: 0, maxY: 0};
    hasRelativeCoordinates = true;

    /**
     * Array of attributes to send with buffers. do not modify
     * @private
     *//** @ts-ignore */
    vertexSource = `
        precision mediump float;

        attribute vec2 aPosition;
        attribute vec2 aUvs;

        uniform float uStepW;
        uniform float uStepH;

        varying vec2 vUvs;

        vec2 uResolution;

        void main() {
            vUvs = aUvs;
            uResolution = vec2(uStepW, uStepH);

            gl_Position = vec4(uResolution * aPosition * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    `;

    fragmentSource = `
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec2 vUvs;
        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vUvs);
        }
    `;

    /**
     * Return a map of attribute names to WebGLAttributeLocation objects.
     *
     * @param {WebGLRenderingContext} gl The canvas context used to compile the shader program.
     * @param {WebGLShaderProgram} program The shader program from which to take attribute locations.
     * @returns {Object} A map of attribute names to attribute locations.
     */
    getAttributeLocations(gl, program) {
        return {
            aPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aPosition'),
            aUvs: gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aUvs'),
        };
    }

    /**
     * Send attribute data from this filter to its shader program on the GPU.
     *
     * @param {WebGLRenderingContext} gl The canvas context used to compile the shader program.
     * @param {Object} attributeLocations A map of shader attribute names to their locations.
     */
    sendAttributeData(gl, attributeLocations, data, type = 'aPosition') {
        const attributeLocation = attributeLocations[type];
        if (gl[type + 'vertexBuffer'] == null) {
            gl[type + 'vertexBuffer'] = gl.createBuffer();
        }

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl[type+'vertexBuffer']);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    generateSurface() {
        const corners = this.perspectiveCoords;

        const surface = verb.geom.NurbsSurface.byCorners(...corners);
        const tess = surface.tessellate();

        return tess;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the resize filter to the image
     * Determines whether to use WebGL or Canvas2D based on the options.webgl flag.
     *
     * @param {Object} options
     * @param {Number} options.passes The number of filters remaining to be executed
     * @param {Boolean} options.webgl Whether to use webgl to render the filter.
     * @param {WebGLTexture} options.sourceTexture The texture setup as the source to be filtered.
     * @param {WebGLTexture} options.targetTexture The texture where filtered output should be drawn.
     * @param {WebGLRenderingContext} options.context The GL context used for rendering.
     * @param {Object} options.programCache A map of compiled shader programs, keyed by filter type.
     */
    applyTo(options) {
        if (options.webgl) {
            const { width, height } = this.getPerspectiveBounds();
            options.context.canvas.width = width;
            options.context.canvas.height = height;

            options.destinationWidth = width;
            options.destinationHeight = height;

            this.hasRelativeCoordinates && this.calculateCoordsByCorners();

            this._setupFrameBuffer(options);
            this.applyToWebGL(options);
            this._swapTextures(options);
        }
    }

    applyPixelRatio(coords = this.perspectiveCoords) {
        for(let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            coords[i][0] *= this.pixelRatio;
            coords[i][1] *= this.pixelRatio;
        }

        return coords;
    }

    getPerspectiveBounds(coords = this.perspectiveCoords) {
        coords = this.perspectiveCoords.slice().map(c => (
            {
                x: c[0],
                y: c[1],
            }
        ));

        this.bounds.minX = fabric.util.array.min(coords, 'x') || 0;
        this.bounds.minY = fabric.util.array.min(coords, 'y') || 0;
        this.bounds.maxX = fabric.util.array.max(coords, 'x') || 0;
        this.bounds.maxY = fabric.util.array.max(coords, 'y') || 0;

        this.bounds.width = Math.abs(this.bounds.maxX - this.bounds.minX);
        this.bounds.height = Math.abs(this.bounds.maxY - this.bounds.minY);

        return {
            width:  this.bounds.width,
            height: this.bounds.height,
            minX:   this.bounds.minX,
            maxX:   this.bounds.maxX,
            minY:   this.bounds.minY,
            maxY:   this.bounds.maxY,
        };
    }

    /**
     * @description coordinates are coming in relative to mockup item sections
     * the following function normalizes the coords based on canvas corners
     *
     * @param {number[]} coords
     */
    calculateCoordsByCorners(coords = this.perspectiveCoords) {
        for(let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            coords[i][0] -= this.bounds.minX;
            coords[i][1] -= this.bounds.minY;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply this filter using webgl.
     *
     * @param {Object} options
     * @param {Number} options.passes The number of filters remaining to be executed
     * @param {Boolean} options.webgl Whether to use webgl to render the filter.
     * @param {WebGLTexture} options.originalTexture The texture of the original input image.
     * @param {WebGLTexture} options.sourceTexture The texture setup as the source to be filtered.
     * @param {WebGLTexture} options.targetTexture The texture where filtered output should be drawn.
     * @param {WebGLRenderingContext} options.context The GL context used for rendering.
     * @param {Object} options.programCache A map of compiled shader programs, keyed by filter type.
     */
    applyToWebGL(options) {
        const gl = options.context;
        const shader = this.retrieveShader(options);
        const tess = this.generateSurface(options.sourceWidth, options.sourceHeight);
        const indices = new Uint16Array(_.flatten(tess.faces));

        // Clear the canvas first
        this.clear(gl); // !important

        // bind texture buffer
        this.bindTexture(gl, options);

        gl.useProgram(shader.program);

        // create the buffer
        this.indexBuffer(gl, indices);

        this.sendAttributeData(gl, shader.attributeLocations, new Float32Array(_.flatten(tess.points)), 'aPosition');
        this.sendAttributeData(gl, shader.attributeLocations, new Float32Array(_.flatten(tess.uvs)), 'aUvs');

        gl.uniform1f(shader.uniformLocations.uStepW, 1 / gl.canvas.width);
        gl.uniform1f(shader.uniformLocations.uStepH, 1 / gl.canvas.height);

        this.sendUniformData(gl, shader.uniformLocations);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, options.destinationWidth, options.destinationHeight);

        // enable indices up to 4294967296 for webGL 1.0
        gl.getExtension('OES_element_index_uint');
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }

    clear(gl) {
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    bindTexture(gl, options) {
        if (options.pass === 0 && options.originalTexture) {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, options.originalTexture);
        } else {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, options.sourceTexture);
        }

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }

    indexBuffer(gl, data) {
        const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        // make this buffer the current 'ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER'
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
        // Fill the current element array buffer with data
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }
};

/**
 * Returns filter instance from an object representation
 * @static
 * @param {Object} object Object to create an instance from
 * @param {function} [callback] to be invoked after filter creation
 * @return {fabric.Image.filters.Perspective} Instance of fabric.Image.filters.Perspective
 */
fabric.Image.filters.Perspective.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter.fromObject;


/**
 * Photo subclass
 * @class fabric.Photo
 * @extends fabric.Photo
 * @return {fabric.Photo} thisArg
 *
 */
fabric.Photo = class extends fabric.Image {
    type = 'photo';
    repeat = 'no-repeat';
    fill = 'transparent';
    initPerspective = true;

    cacheProperties = fabric.Image.prototype.cacheProperties.concat('perspectiveCoords');

    constructor(src, options) {
        super(options);

        if (options) this.setOptions(options);

        this.on('added', () => {
            const image = new Image();
            image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
            image.onload = () => {
                this._initElement(image, options);
                this.width = image.width / 2;
                this.height = image.height / 2;
                this.loaded = true;
                this.setCoords();
                this.fire('image:loaded');
            };
            image.src = src;
    
            this.on('image:loaded', () => {
                !this.perspectiveCoords && this.getInitialPerspective();
        
                this.togglePerspective();
                this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
            });
        });
    }

    cacheProperties = fabric.Image.prototype.cacheProperties.concat('perspectiveCoords');

    /**
     * @private
     * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx Context to render on
     *//** @ts-ignore */
    _render(ctx) {
        fabric.util.setImageSmoothing(ctx, this.imageSmoothing);

        if (this.isMoving !== true && this.resizeFilter && this._needsResize()) {
          this.applyResizeFilters();
        }

        this._stroke(ctx);
        this._renderPaintInOrder(ctx);
    }

    /**
     * @private
     * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx Context to render on
     *//** @ts-ignore */
    _renderFill(ctx) {
        var elementToDraw = this._element;
        if (!elementToDraw) return;

        ctx.save();
        const elWidth = elementToDraw.naturalWidth || elementToDraw.width;
        const elHeight = elementToDraw.naturalHeight || elementToDraw.height;
        const width = this.width;
        const height = this.height;

        ctx.translate(-width / 2, -height / 2);

        // get the scale
        const scale = Math.min(width / elWidth, height / elHeight);
        // get the top left position of the image
        const x = (width / 2) - (elWidth / 2) * scale;
        const y = (height / 2) - (elHeight / 2) * scale;

        ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw, x, y, elWidth * scale, elHeight * scale);

        ctx.restore();
    }

    togglePerspective(mode = true) {
        this.set('perspectiveMode', mode);
        // this.set('hasBorders', !mode);

        if (mode === true) {
            this.set('layout', 'fit');

            var lastControl = this.perspectiveCoords.length - 1;

            this.controls = this.perspectiveCoords.reduce((acc, coord, index) => {
                const anchorIndex = index > 0 ? index - 1 : lastControl;
                let name = `prs${index + 1}`;

                acc[name] = new fabric.Control({
                    name,
                    x: -0.5,
                    y: -0.5,
                    actionHandler: this._actionWrapper(anchorIndex, (_, transform, x, y) => {
                        const target = transform.target;
                        const localPoint = target.toLocalPoint(new fabric.Point(x, y), 'left', 'top');

                        coord[0] = localPoint.x / target.scaleX * fabric.devicePixelRatio;
                        coord[1] = localPoint.y / target.scaleY * fabric.devicePixelRatio;

                        target.setCoords();
                        target.applyFilters();

                        return true;
                    }),
                    positionHandler: function (dim, finalMatrix, fabricObject) {
                        const zoom = fabricObject.canvas.getZoom();
                        const scalarX = fabricObject.scaleX * zoom / fabric.devicePixelRatio;
                        const scalarY = fabricObject.scaleY * zoom / fabric.devicePixelRatio;

                        var point = fabric.util.transformPoint({
                                x: this.x * dim.x + this.offsetX + coord[0] * scalarX,
                                y: this.y * dim.y + this.offsetY + coord[1] * scalarY,
                            }, finalMatrix
                        );

                        return point;
                    },
                    cursorStyleHandler: () => 'cell',
                    render: function(ctx, left, top, _, fabricObject) {
                        const zoom = fabricObject.canvas.getZoom();
                        const scalarX = fabricObject.scaleX * zoom / fabric.devicePixelRatio;
                        const scalarY = fabricObject.scaleY * zoom / fabric.devicePixelRatio;

                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(left, top);
                        ctx.rotate(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(fabricObject.angle));
                        ctx.beginPath();

                        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

                        if (fabricObject.perspectiveCoords[index + 1]) {
                            ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
                            ctx.lineTo(
                                (fabricObject.perspectiveCoords[index + 1][0] - coord[0]) * scalarX,
                                (fabricObject.perspectiveCoords[index + 1][1] - coord[1]) * scalarY,
                            );
                        } else {
                            ctx.lineTo(
                                (fabricObject.perspectiveCoords[0][0] - coord[0]) * scalarX,
                                (fabricObject.perspectiveCoords[0][1] - coord[1]) * scalarY,
                            );
                        }
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(0, 0, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.restore();
                    },
                    offsetX: 0,
                    offsetY: 0,
                    actionName: 'perspective-coords',
                });

                return acc;
            }, {});
        } else {
            this.controls = fabric.Photo.prototype.controls;
        }

        this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }

    _actionWrapper(anchorIndex, fn) {
        return function(eventData, transform, x, y) {
            if (!transform || !eventData) return;

            const { target } = transform;

            target._resetSizeAndPosition(anchorIndex);

            const actionPerformed = fn(eventData, transform, x, y);
            return actionPerformed;
        };
    }

    /**
     * @description manually reset the bounding box after points update
     *
     * @see http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon
     * @param {number} index
     */
    _resetSizeAndPosition = (index, apply = true) => {
        const absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint({
            x: this.perspectiveCoords[index][0],
            y: this.perspectiveCoords[index][1],
        }, this.calcTransformMatrix());

        this._setPositionDimensions({});

        const penBaseSize = this._getNonTransformedDimensions();
        const newX = (this.perspectiveCoords[index][0]) / penBaseSize.x;
        const newY = (this.perspectiveCoords[index][1]) / penBaseSize.y;

        this.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX + 0.5, newY + 0.5);

        apply && this._applyPointsOffset();
    }

    /**
     * This is modified version of the internal fabric function
     * this helps determine the size and the location of the path
     *
     * @param {object} options
     */
    _setPositionDimensions(options) {
        const { left, top, width, height } = this._calcDimensions(options);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        var correctLeftTop = this.translateToGivenOrigin(
            {
                x: left,
                y: top,
            },
            'left',
            'top',
            this.originX,
            this.originY
        );

        if (typeof options.left === 'undefined') {
            this.left = correctLeftTop.x;
        }
        if (typeof options.top === 'undefined') {
            this.top = correctLeftTop.y;
        }

        this.pathOffset = {
            x: left,
            y: top,
        };

        return { left, top, width, height };
    }

    /**
     * @description this is based on fabric.Path._calcDimensions
     *
     * @private
     */
    _calcDimensions() {
        const coords = this.perspectiveCoords.slice().map(c => (
            {
                x: c[0] / fabric.devicePixelRatio,
                y: c[1] / fabric.devicePixelRatio,
            }
        ));

        const minX = fabric.util.array.min(coords, 'x') || 0;
        const minY = fabric.util.array.min(coords, 'y') || 0;
        const maxX = fabric.util.array.max(coords, 'x') || 0;
        const maxY = fabric.util.array.max(coords, 'y') || 0;

        const width = Math.abs(maxX - minX);
        const height = Math.abs(maxY - minY);

        return {
            left: minX,
            top: minY,
            width: width,
            height: height,
        };
    }

    /**
     * @description This is modified version of the internal fabric function
     * this subtracts the path offset from each path points
     */
    _applyPointsOffset() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.perspectiveCoords.length; i++) {
            const coord = this.perspectiveCoords[i];

            coord[0] -= this.pathOffset.x;
            coord[1] -= this.pathOffset.y;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description generate the initial coordinates for warping, based on image dimensions
     *
     */
    getInitialPerspective() {
        let w = this.getScaledWidth();
        let h = this.getScaledHeight();

        const perspectiveCoords = [
            [0, 0], // top left
            [w, 0], // top right
            [w, h], // bottom right
            [0, h], // bottom left
        ];

        this.perspectiveCoords = perspectiveCoords;

        const perspectiveFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Perspective({
            hasRelativeCoordinates: false,
            pixelRatio: fabric.devicePixelRatio, // the Photo is already retina ready
            perspectiveCoords
        });

        this.filters.push(perspectiveFilter);
        this.applyFilters();

        return perspectiveCoords;
    }
};

/**
 * Creates an instance of fabric.Photo from its object representation
 * @static
 * @param {Object} object Object to create an instance from
 * @param {Function} callback Callback to invoke when an image instance is created
 */
fabric.Photo.fromObject = function(_object, callback) {
    const object = fabric.util.object.clone(_object);
    object.layout = _object.layout;

    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function(img, isError) {
        if (isError) {
            callback && callback(null, true);

            return;
        }
        fabric.Photo.prototype._initFilters.call(object, object.filters, function(filters) {
            object.filters = filters || [];
            fabric.Photo.prototype._initFilters.call(object, [object.resizeFilter], function(resizeFilters) {
                object.resizeFilter = resizeFilters[0];

                fabric.util.enlivenObjects([object.clipPath], function(enlivedProps) {
                    object.clipPath = enlivedProps[0];
                    var image = new fabric.Photo(img, object);

                    callback(image, false);
                });
            });
        });
    }, null, object.crossOrigin || 'anonymous');
};


const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  enableRetinaScaling: true,
});

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
}

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener('resize', () => resizeCanvas(), false);

const photo = new fabric.Photo('https://cdn.artboard.studio/private/5cb9c751-5f17-4062-adb7-6ec2c137a65d/user_uploads/5bafe170-1580-4d6b-a3be-f5cdce22d17d-asdasdasd.jpg', {
  left: canvas.getWidth() / 2,
  top: canvas.getHeight() / 2,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
});

canvas.add(photo);
canvas.setActiveObject(photo);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/verb-nurbs-web@2.1.3/build/js/verb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fabric@4.3.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reference to `absolutePoint` in `_resetSizeAndPosition` needs to take into account the origin for the image and that there is a simple fix to this issue.  However, I didn't find a good way to do this and resorted to manually "correcting" this issue in `_resetSizeAndPosition`.

The modified version of `_resetSizeAndPosition` looks like so:

```
    _resetSizeAndPosition = (index, apply = true) => {
        const absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint({
            x: this.perspectiveCoords[index][0],
            y: this.perspectiveCoords[index][1],
        }, this.calcTransformMatrix());

        let { height, width, left, top } = this._calcDimensions({});

        const widthDiff = (width - this.width) / 2;
        if ((left < 0 && widthDiff > 0) || (left > 0 && widthDiff < 0)) {
            absolutePoint.x -= widthDiff;
        } else {
            absolutePoint.x += widthDiff;
        }

        const heightDiff = (height - this.height) / 2;
        if ((top < 0 && heightDiff > 0) || (top > 0 && heightDiff < 0)) {
            absolutePoint.y -= heightDiff;
        } else {
            absolutePoint.y += heightDiff;
        }
        this._setPositionDimensions({});

        const penBaseSize = this._getNonTransformedDimensions();
        const newX = (this.perspectiveCoords[index][0]) / penBaseSize.x;
        const newY = (this.perspectiveCoords[index][1]) / penBaseSize.y;

        this.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX + 0.5, newY + 0.5);

        apply && this._applyPointsOffset();
    }
```

The basic principle for this approach is that the `left` and `top` properties of the object are never being updated.  This can be seen in your example through the console by modifying the image and checking the properties on the image.  Therefore, we need to apply a correction to the position properties based on the changing width and height.  This ensures that other points stay fixed in place, since we compensate for the changing height and width of the image in its position.

By comparing the values of `width` and `this.width` it's possible to determine if the image is increasing or decreasing in size.  The value of `left` indicates whether the stretch is occurring to the left or right side of the image.  If the user is stretching the image to the left or shrinking it from the right then we need.  By combining the conditions for these, we can tell how we need to modify the position of the image to compensate.  The same approach used for the horizontal values is also applied to the vertical values.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0x8caow6/

Comment: Thanks ben, actually the `left` and `top` ARE being applied in `_setPositionDimensions` function (notice lines 508 and 511) while your code works better than mine, there is a jittering happening when dragging the sides, as if the other points move and then they jump back to their designated position, any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: The changes made to `left` and `top` in `_setPositionDimensions` are overwritten when `setPositionByOrigin` is called.  The issue with the jittering is noticeable in both versions of the code when the size of the picture is modified is increased beyond the original size.  It seems to be something with the filter itself, although the filter might be receiving temporary bad values during the drag.